# ClientBase to create channel method

Tags: c#, wcf

I have followed the tutorial in the following link: http://wcftutorial.net/WCF-Self-Hosting.aspx to learn basic selfhosting, where I am stuck at number 10.

Could someone explain how the xml file is supposed to work out for me? I should create a similar xml file, but what extension and where should I save it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an App.Config file for the project. Then copy the file contents to that file, and build the project. It should work.